# "Dependents.Count" statement restarting macro when used in "Worksheet_SelectionChange" Sub

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling, onclick, dependencies

I am trying to get number of dependents of selected range (if number of cells in selection is one). When I use following code it works without any error for all cells (for cells without any dependents and for cells having dependents)

```
'Case 1
Sub Example()
    Dim rng As Excel.Range
    Set rng = Excel.Selection
    If Target.Count = 1 Then
        If HasDependents(rng) Then
            MsgBox rng.Dependents.Count & " dependancies found."
        Else
            MsgBox "No dependancies found."
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Public Function HasDependents(ByVal Something As Excel.Range) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    HasDependents = Something.Dependents.Count
End Function
```

But when same logic is used in Worksheet_SelectionChange (as shown in following code)

```
'Case 2
Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    If Target.Count = 1 Then
        If HasDependents(Target) Then
            MsgBox Target.Dependents.Count & " dependancies found."
        Else
            MsgBox "No dependancies found."
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Public Function HasDependents(ByVal Something As Excel.Range) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    HasDependents = Something.Dependents.Count
End Function
```

it works for cells not having any dependents, but for cells having dependents "Dependents.Count" restarts macro. After executing

```
HasDependents = Something.Dependents.Count
```

Statement, macro restarts and executes

```
Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
```

again. My question is
 **why macro is restarting in second case after executing "Dependents.Count"?** 
 For "Worksheet_SelectionChange" I have put the code in Sheet Code area not in module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asking for the [Dependents property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa214281.aspx) appears to be triggering the cell selection event. Additionally, whenever no dependents are found an **Error 1004: No cells were found.** was thrown. The retrieval of the dependents appears to be recursive; going into each found as a dependent to find another layer of dependents.

I've stabilized your process by adding a call to disable the [Application.EnableEvents property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821508.aspx) so that the routine was not being called by itself.

```
Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    If Target.Count = 1 Then
        On Error GoTo bm_Err_Exit
        Dim dc As Long
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        dc = Target.Dependents.Count
        If CBool(dc) Then
            'MsgBox Target.Address(0, 0) & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & _
                    dc & " dependancies found."
            Debug.Print Target.Address(0, 0) & Chr(10) & _
                    dc & " dependancies found."
        Else
            'never reaches here; error 1004 is thrown when no dependents
            'MsgBox "No dependancies found."
            Debug.Print "No dependancies found."
        End If
    End If
bm_Safe_Exit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
bm_Err_Exit:
    Debug.Print Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Basic error control reported the 1004 errors when the current select had no dependents.

---

¹ <sub>You may want to explore the [DirectDependents property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa175238.aspx) as well as the [Dependents property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa214281.aspx).</sub>